# проблема в отображении frameset при подключении к django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

суть такая, есть код
#index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows=100% >
        <frameset rows=76%,24% >
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=reports src="reports.html" >
                <frame name=fg_log src=/****.py >
            </frameset>
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=fp_log src=/********.py?fp=3&files=on >
                <frame name=ls src=/*******.py >
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

при запуске просто открыв index.html через браузер - я вижу данные первого фрейма [image: ВЕРНО]

но если запустить отображение этого же index.html через django - я в место hello world - вижу 404 [image: НЕВЕРНО]

и в терминале так же вижу ошибку [image: ОШИБКА]